# Cannot install FsLab with NuGet

Tags: nuget, deedle, fslab

Complete VS noob. Fresh install of Visual Studio Community 2015. New project. Trying to install FsLab with NuGet ends with this error:

```
Unable to find a version of 'Deedle' that is compatible with 'FsLab 1.0.2 constraint: Deedle (= 1.2.5)'
```

When I search for Deedle the version that NuGet shows *is* v1.2.5.

I suspect this is a NuGet problem after reading about some issues with its dependency resolution management.

I tried installing Deedle separately and setting NuGet's `Dependency behavior` to `Highest` with no luck. In the end I installed [Paket](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket) which worked with no problems. No time to debug this further for now.

Comment: Just experienced the same thing - cheers for the heads up on Paket